# How to know under which account/Apple ID an app was purchased?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

I uninstalled/removed apps I used to purchase using a family member's Apple ID; then I re-purchased apps using my own Apple ID.

Is there a way for me to check whether the apps are now under my Apple ID? I would like to ensure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of now:

- Follow [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2727) step-by-step program to see your complete purchase history
- Remove the app, make sure you're logged in on the right account and check if the just removed app has a cloud-symbol instead of "purchase" next to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see my purchase history in my own Apple ID. And I noticed that some of them got a new update and they are now through my own Apple ID.
I didn't see the cloud symbol too.

Thank you very much for your help!