# Retrieve the Apple ID used to download a given app (in iphone)

Tags: iphone, applications, apple-id

I have an iphone, which has some apps installed. The Apple ID used to sign in (to iTunes store and App strore) is, say, ID1.
When updating apps, in some cases it asks for the password of another ID, say, ID2.

*Is there any way to know what Apple ID is associated with each app?*

I know that I can remove an app and purchase it under a different ID (which may have cost), and I know that there exists Family sharing, but that does not answer the question.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/162679/87077) is a related question.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone you can use the Setting app to set the default ID for App Store under "iTunes and App Store"

Set ID1.

Open App Store -> Updates. At the top you can click Purchased to see all apps purchased with that account.

Then, go back to settings, sign in to ID2, and go back to the App Store and check to see ID2s list.

Comment: This does not seem to give the ID associated with the app installed in the device. For instance, I have purchased a given app with both IDs, and with the procedure you suggest it shows up under both lists. So, I cannot know which ID is associated with the one installed in the device.