# Viewing the Apple ID in iTunes' app list?

Tags: itunes

I'm using Windows 7 and I'd like to be able to group my apps by Apple ID, but there is no option from the list view:

[image]

If I browse to the directory using Windows Explorer I also cannot see the Apple ID listed.

Is there anyway to quickly see which Apple ID each app belongs to?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162679/retrieve-the-apple-id-used-to-download-a-given-app-in-itunes?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, I have around 500 apps though so it'd be quite time consuming to zip up each one and then open it up and go into that file... but I guess it's better than nothing, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, expected something like that. On OSX I would recommend to write a shell script to automate that, maybe PowerShell will help in an Windows environment. But this is off-topic for AD.